# Verifying Transformation is Skew Symmetric

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $V$ be a vector space of dimension $2n$, and let $s = \begin{bmatrix}0 & I_n \\ -I_n & 0 \end{bmatrix}$. The textbook I'm reading claims that $s$ is a skew-symmetric bilinear form, but $s(u, v) = (v, -u)$ while $-s(v, u) = (-u, v)$. I'm sure I'm making some awful mistake, since this matrix obviously satisfies $s^T = -s$, but could someone help me see it?

Comment: A bilinear form is not a linear transformation. Both may be represented by matrices, but in different ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The matrix is representing a bilinear form $B$ if you take $B(u,v) = u^\top s(v)$.